# Oracle java tutorial - possible error regarding Character autoboxing java comment

Tags: java, autoboxing

I'm new to JAVA, currently learning Oracle tutorial generics section. I think there is a mistake there, and I want to make sure I'm not wrong. I'll appreciate your feedback.

I saw the following explanation at
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html

> Pair < Integer, Character > p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');
>
> Note that the Java compiler autoboxes 8 to Integer.valueOf(8) and **'a' to Character('a')**:
>
> Pair < Integer, Character > p = new Pair<>(Integer.valueOf(8), **new Character('a')**);

I think this is a mistake and 'a' is actually auto-boxed to **Character.valueOf('a')**.

I wrote the following program to check it. as I thought maybe generics have special boxing, I tried generic method, regular method and generic class:

```
class TestCharacter<T>{
public <T> void check( T first, T second){
    System.out.println("values: " + first + "  " + second);
    System.out.println(first.equals(second));
    System.out.println( "first == second is " + (first == second) );
    System.out.println( "first == second is " + (first == Character.valueOf('a')) );
}
}

public class TestAutoBoxingIssue{

public static <T> void check1( T first, T second){
    System.out.println("values: " + first + "  " + second);
    System.out.println(first.equals(second));
    System.out.println( "first == second is " + (first == second) );
    System.out.println( "first == second is " + (first == Character.valueOf('a')) );
}
public static void check2( Character first, Character second){
    System.out.println("values: " + first + "  " + second);
    System.out.println(first.equals(second));
    System.out.println( "first == second is " + (first == second) );
    System.out.println( "first == second is " + (first == Character.valueOf('a')) );
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    char first = 'a';
    char second = 'a';
    System.out.println("generic method usage: ");
    check1( first, second );
    System.out.println("=============");

    System.out.println("regular method usage: ");
    check2( first, second );
    System.out.println("=============");

    TestCharacter<Character> t = new TestCharacter<>();
    System.out.println("generic class usage: ");
    t.check(first, second );
    System.out.println("=============");
}
```

}

output is:

generic method usage: 
values: a  a
true
first == second is true

## **first == second is true**

regular method usage: 
values: a  a
true
first == second is true

## **first == second is true**

generic class usage: 
values: a  a
true
first == second is true

## **first == second is true**

So, I think this demonstrates that 'a' is autoboxed to Character.valueOf.

Am I missing something? Is this the right way to check it?

Thanks.

Eliyahu

Comment: The point of the question was the comment at Oracle java tutorial, which I thought is wrong. therefore, I think it is not a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, autoboxing is done with `valueOf` everywhere to take advantage of any caches. For example with `Character`:

```
public static Character valueOf(char c) {
    if (c <= 127) { // must cache
        return CharacterCache.cache[(int)c];
    }
    return new Character(c);
}
```

It's a documentation oversight.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I thought autoboxing is done by valueOf by got confused from the tutorial comment. So if it is an oversight, it is OK. Thanks for the feedback.